# Spring Data JPA saveAll/Save method as batch insert

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have noticed the behaviour of the save method performing the insert as a batch when setting `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.order_inserts=true`. The `saveAll` is indeed doing the batch insert. But what I found strange is that the save method is doing batch as well.
Is that normal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is normal. In the end, batching is a Hibernate feature and Spring just calls `persist`/`merge` on the `EntityManager`. Hibernate figures out behind the scenes how it can do batching.